# How to get the name of connected ios phone in Linux using command

Tags: application-development, qt, c++

How to get the name of connected ios device name in Linux, or c++ programming. basically, I use the Qt in Linux. and I want to get the name of the connected device name. after a searching in google we met a UIdevice class. By writing UIDevice.currentDevice().name we get the name of the iPhone. but the UIdevice is a class of Objective C. I also follow the following steps: - reference - https://wiki.qt.io/IOS_device_info

All methods, usage Objective-C code. You could use Objective-C in your application on C++. All you need it, just add new class with header *. h and implementation file *. mm. Then add this file to you *.pro using special keywords:

OBJECTIVE_HEADERS += \
    Helpers/iOS/redminedevicehelper.h

OBJECTIVE_SOURCES += \
    Helpers/iOS/redminedevicehelper.mm

Also, you need to use frameworks to get access to basic Objective-C classes and methods:

```
UIKit

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

Foundation

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

In the *.pro file you need add this framework as a library:

LIBS += -framework Foundation -framework CoreFoundation -framework UIKit
How to access the UIDevice class in qt.

But nothing done.

Please help me..if any one know about this. Sorry for my Bad English.
**I installed the libimobiledevice packages in Linux.**

***Thanks,***
Ram Kumar.

Comment: By linux do you mean Ubuntu, if not this may not be the stack exchange site you need!

Comment: yes, i use the ubuntu os.

Answer (score 0):

In mac ,Carbon cocoa is used . then all the objective-c headers files are used.
in Linux, carbon-cocoa is not used.so that objective-c headers files are not supported in Linux.